# Do I need to install oracle db before using sql developer?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

do I need to install oracle db before using sql developer? I just install Oracle Sql Developer and I'm getting a message box saying: "Enter the full pathname for java.exe".

It looks to me like Oracle Sql developer is like the Sql Server Management Studio, which works on top of the Sql Server.

Answer (score 5):

The first thing you'll need is a JDK installation. The message Enter "the full pathname for java.exe" refers to that. You'll need to provide the path of the 'bin' folder in the installed JDK

After that, yes you'll need a database installed on your PC or a remotely accessible DB will also suffice. SQL developer provides just a UI for running your SQL, PL/SQL queries. Its an IDE, not a database

Comment: which oracle version do I need then?

Comment: You can get also an installer that includes a JDK; see [the installation guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25259_01/doc.31/e26419/install.htm#CIHDJBJG).

Answer (score 1):

Oracle Database includes SQL Developer but SQL Developer doesn't include a database. You have a few options for getting up and running quickly.

http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/12/i-have-oracle-sql-developer-installed-now-what/

Technically you can use SQL Developer without any database. It has an offline editor, data modeling component, and other features which do not require a database connection.